# Advanced query with joined tables and multiple values from GET parameter

Tags: php, sql, get

First of all I'm going to explain what I want to happen in the end so if you can't help me you don't waste your time reading all of this :)

I'm creating an API in which it outputs possible illnesses that a user could have, based on the symptoms they submitted.

I want the user to input something, this goes into the url as "symptom=...
like: .../nameofmyapi/data?symptoms=headache+dizzyness. I retrieve the data from the GET parameter, but I have absolutely no idea on how to output the name of the illness.

My database looks like this:

- **illness**

  - *illnessId (int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT)*
  - *illnessName(varchar(255))*
- **symptom**

  - *symptomId (int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT)*
  - *symptomName (varchar(255))*
- **illness_symptom**

  - *illnessId (from the illness table)*
  - *symptomId (from the symptom table)*

This database design makes sure you dont get multiple values in 1 row and don't have the same values BUT like I said, I don't know how to "search" or "filter" illnesses based on values from the other table. Let alone having multiple symptoms to check on... seems impossible!

I've got this query though, so I can retrieve everything when the user did not input anything:

```
"SELECT illness.illnessId, illness.illnessName, symptom.symptomName FROM illness_symptom
 JOIN illness
 ON illness.illnessId = illness_symptom.illnessId
 JOIN symptom
 ON symptom.symptomId = illness_symptom.symptomId";
```

Which gives me this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY0YM.png)

Like I said, I only want to output "Whiplash" when the url looks like this:/nameofmyapi/data?symptoms=dizzyness+headache

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all: To only output 'Whiplash' is not going to work because your other illness is also connected to the symptom 'dizzyness'.

I've created a database with your structure (only renamed the fields to have more default convention. Would also look at your table names to pluralfy them) and came up with this query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name
FROM illness_symptom AS ils
JOIN illness AS i ON i.id = ils.illness_id
JOIN symptom AS s ON s.id = ils.symptom_id
WHERE s.name IN ('dizzyness',  'headache')
GROUP BY i.name
```

The IN part searches through your table and filters out all the other results with different symptoms. You could convert the result from your GET query to a comma separated list used in the query.

The GROUP BY part makes sure you won't get any double results. Off course you need to make sure a result only exists in your DB once (no double records with different case like 'whiplaSh').

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Antwan! I could not get the WHERE .. IN to work in my query but now it works perfectly! Not all heroes wear capes! :)